# Does Duplication Potion count towards the Velvet Choker's card limit?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The Velvet Choker relic effect states "You cannot play more than 6 cards per turn". The Duplication Potion's description says "This turn, your next two cards are played twice". If I use a Duplication Potion, do cards that get played twice count as two cards for the Velvet Choker's 6 card limit?

Comment: Been a long time since I've played, but if I recall correctly, the Choker has a counter to how many cards have been played. It would be a pretty easy to see if you get into this situation again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, whenever a card is copied (via the Duplication Potion or cards like [Echo Form](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Echo_Form) and [Double Tap](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Double_Tap)) the copy will count as a card played for effects that count cards, such as the [Velvet Choker](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Velvet_Choker) or [Time Eater](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Eater)'s Time Warp effect.